# Why is my code working on codepen but not on my editor?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, google-font-api

I am using sublime 3 for html and css.

I have saved the files with proper extension. Have used google fonts to add the font "Lobster". When I open this `.html` file on google chrome, it isn't working (i.e., the lobster font) but it's working when I try to run it on codepen. I'm using a system running on windows xp. I tried running the same thing on my laptop with windows 10 and the chrome browser is updated but the problem isn't going.

It's working on the editor of stack overflow as well.

```css
.nav-pills {
  font-family: Lobster;
  font-size: 2.2em;
  background-color:black;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Puneeth</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="portfolio.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <ul class="nav nav-pills">
        <li><a href="#">Puneeth S</a></li>
        <li class="pull-right"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        <li class="pull-right"><a href="#">Portolio</a></li>
        <li class="pull-right"><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li class="pull-right"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: so the css is working but the only thing not working is the lobster font?

Comment: Any errors in the `console`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you load the html file locally into your browser, it will use the `file:` protocol. And since you have `href="//fonts.googleapis.com` for the font, the browser will attempt to load that one too using the `file:` protocol.

Solution: use the full URL for the font path, including the proper protocol.

```
href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/...
```

The reason that it works here in a SO snippet or on codepen is that you call up these pages with `http:` already.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```css
.nav-pills {
    /*edit your  font-family in css and the code will work done */
  font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
  font-size: 2.2em;
  background-color:black;
}
```

to use google fonts you should follow the rules

Comment: Which rule wasn't the OP following then? While I agree that using quotes around font names is a good idea, they are not necessary in this case, where `Lobster` isn't a CSS keyword. So the OP _was_ following the rules.

Comment: in this case you use  font  family locally but op use font family with http protocol