# My code is working on codepen but not on my editor

Tags: javascript, css, django

My code is working on codepen but not on my editor (PyCharm). This is part of django project. By not working I mean I get a blank page, with no output (no text). I expect to see some text appearing on the screen with infinite scroll

I have tried to read a few answers addressing a similar issue but none of these solutions seem to be working for me/or I am not applying them correctly. [Specifically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38812196/why-is-my-code-working-on-codepen-but-not-on-my-editor) adding the full URL path for getting ScrollWatch through CDN. Here is a sample of my code

html

```html
{ % load script % }
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>The Gradient Boost</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'second/css/app/book.css' %}">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/scrollwatch@2.0.1/dist/ScrollWatch-2.0.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h2><div data-scroll-watch>First Text</div></h2>
<h2><div data-scroll-watch>Second Text</div></h2>
<h3><div data-scroll-watch>Third Text</div></h3>
<script src="{% static 'second/js/app/book.js' %}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

css
location -> static\second\css\app\book.css

```
.watch-container {
    font-size: 2em;
    width: 75%;
    height: 150px;
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 50px auto;
    background-color: #0681CD;
    color: #fff;
    overflow: auto;
    text-align: center;

}

div {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1em;
    margin: 200px 0;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 1s;
    font-weight: normal
}

div.scroll-watch-in-view {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

and javascript
location -> static\second\js\app\book.js

```
(function() {

    var addElements = function() {

        var txt = document.createTextNode('Testing');
        var el;

        el = document.createElement('div');
        el.appendChild(txt);
        document.body.appendChild(el);

        // If we want newly injected elements to be watched, refresh ScrollWatch. It will re-query the dom and start watching new elements.
        swInstance.refresh();

    };

    var swInstance = new ScrollWatch({
        watch: 'div',
        infiniteScroll: true,
        infiniteOffset: 200,
        onInfiniteYInView: addElements
    });

})();
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong?

This is the error message I am getting on my browser console

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null
    at X.addElements (book.js:10)
    at X.d (ScrollWatch-2.0.1.min.js:662)
    at X.f (ScrollWatch-2.0.1.min.js:662)
    at new X (ScrollWatch-2.0.1.min.js:662)
    at book.js:17
    at book.js:24
DevTools failed to parse SourceMap: chrome-extension://hdokiejnpimakedhajhdlcegeplioahd/sourcemaps/onloadwff.js.map
DevTools failed to parse SourceMap: chrome-extension://hgmhmanijnjhaffoampdlllchpolkdnj/js/lib/purify.min.js.map
```

**UPDATE**
After typing in console.log(el) to try and figure out why el I am getting a null return I started getting another error message:

```
book.js:13 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'refresh' of undefined
    at X.addElements (book.js:13)
    at X.d (ScrollWatch-2.0.1.min.js:662)
    at X.f (ScrollWatch-2.0.1.min.js:662)
    at X.S (ScrollWatch-2.0.1.min.js:662)
    at ScrollWatch-2.0.1.min.js:662
addElements @ book.js:13
d @ ScrollWatch-2.0.1.min.js:662
f @ ScrollWatch-2.0.1.min.js:662
S @ ScrollWatch-2.0.1.min.js:662
(anonymous) @ ScrollWatch-2.0.1.min.js:662
```

Comment: What does "is not working" mean? What behaviour do you expect  and what behaviour/errors do you see? Explain, our brains aren't compilers that can "run" your code and just see what it does.

Comment: And when I say tell us "what you see", it includes opening up your browser developer tools to view any errors in your browser console and report about these. And look in your browser dev tools at your HTML source to see if it matches what you expect from your template.

Comment: @dirkgroten not getting any output, getting a blank screen, amended my question to include that

Comment: @dirkgroten i have included the errors from my browser console too

Comment: So what is exactly line 24 of book.js (which is where the error occurs)? Set a breakpoint in your browser debugger on the line `var txt = document...` and step through your code to observer what value is `null` and why.

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap your script in a `document.onload()` or better `window.onload()` clause:

```
window.onload = function() {

// your script here

}
```

This is because your script is read while creating the `<body>` of the document, so if `body` isn't ready yet, `document.body` will be `null` when your script is running.

Comment: Thanks, tried wrapping my script both in document.onload() and then window.onload() but getting the error: book.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: window.onload is not a function
    at book.js:1

Comment: sorry, am used to the jquery way of doing it. You need to set it equal to your function.

Comment: Thanks. Not sure if this should be a separate question but now getting another error message. Have amended my question

Comment: That's indeed a different issue. But `swInstance` isn't defined inside your function `addElements`. You probably should refresh it outside of your function, after creating it.